# Where to define Nginx process name (nginx) in sources?

Tags: nginx, process, rename, resource-files

Where is the placement of process name ("nginx") definition in sources files? I would like to rename from "nginx" to "nginx1101".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's in src/os/unix/ngx_setproctitle.c:ngx_setproctitle().